# Finding the part of a String that is wrapped in delimeters

Tags: java, regex, recursion

Say I have a `String` like this:

```
String s="social network such as '''[http://www.facebook.com Facebook]''' , "+
"'''[http://www.twitter.com Twitter]''' and '''[http://www.tumblr.com tumblr]'''";
```

and I need to retrieve only those `Strings` within `'''[` and `]'''`.

example output:

```
http://www.facebook.com Facebook, http://www.twitter.com Twitter, http://www.tumblr.com   tumblr
```

I'm having a difficulty doing this using `regex`, so I came with this idea using `recursion`:

```
System.out.println(filter(s, "'''[",  "]'''"));
....

public static String filter(String s, String open, String close){   
  int start = s.indexOf(open);
  int end = s.indexOf(close);

  filtered = filtered + s.substring(start + open.length(), end) + ", ";
  s = s.substring(end + close.length(), s.length());

  if(s.indexOf(open) >= 0 && s.indexOf(close) >= 0)
     return filter(s, open, close);

  else
     return filtered.substring(0, filtered.length() - 2);
}
```

but in some case, where I need to retrieve words within the same pattern of the `String` such as within `'''` and `'''`, it will say *String index out of range* because `start` and `end` will hold the same value.

How can I overcome this? Is `regex` the only solution?

Comment: `start` and `end` shouldn't have the same value unless they're -1 indicating that the string couldn't be found.  Are you checking to make sure both `open` and `close` are present before you call `filter` the _first_ time?  Regardless, I don't know why you'd have trouble using a regex; perhaps if you post the regex you tried we can help you make that work.

Comment: @ajb i mean, when the value of open and close are equal, start and end will also have the same value. Actually i just dont want to use regex, withaut any reason, but if regex is the only solution then i have to.

Comment: But I thought `open` and `close` are `"'''["` and `"]'''"`, so they shouldn't be equal.  If they can be equal, your problem is entirely different.  In that case, I think instead of `end = s.indexOf(close)`, you need to use something like `end = s.substring(start+open.length()).indexOf(close)`, and check first to make sure `start` isn't -1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex is the right tool for this. Use [`Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) and [`Matcher`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html).

```
public static String filter(String s, String open, String close){
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(open) + "(.*?)" + Pattern.quote(close));
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);

    StringBuilder filtered = new StringBuilder();

    while (m.find()){
        filtered.append(m.group(1)).append(", ");
    }
    return filtered.substring(0, filtered.length() - 2); //-2 because trailing ", "
}
```

[`Pattern.quote`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29) ensures that any special characters for `open` and `close` are treated as regular ones.

`m.group()` returns the group from the last `String` matched by `m.find()`.

`m.find()` finds all substrings that match the regex.

---

### Non-regex Solutions:

Note: in both of these, `end` is assigned `s.indexOf(close, start + 1)`, using [`String#indexOf(String, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) and [`StringBuilder#indexOf(String, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#indexOf%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) so that even if the `open` and `close` values are the same, no error occurs.

**Recursion**:

```
public static String filter(String s, String open, String close){
    int start = s.indexOf(open);
    int end = s.indexOf(close, start + 1);

    //I took the liberty of adding "String" and renaming your variable
    String get = s.substring(start + open.length(), end);
    s = s.substring(end + close.length());

    if (s.indexOf(open) == -1){
        return get;
    }
    return get + ", " + filter(s, open, close);
}
```

Rather than adding the `", "` right off the bat, it is a little easier to deal with it later. Also, note that `s.substring(end + close.length(), s.length())` is the same as `s.substring(end + close.length());` Also, I feel that it is neater to see if `s.indexOf(...) == -1` rather than checking for `>=0`.

The real problem lies in the way you treat `filtered`. First of all, you need to declare `filtered` as type `String`. Next, since you are doing recursion, you shouldn't concatenate to `filtered`. That would make the line where we first see `filtered`: `String filtered = s.substring(start + open.length(), end) + ", ";`. If you fix that line, your solution works.

**Iterative**:

```
public static String filter(String str, String open, String close){
    int open_length = open.length();
    int close_length = close.length();

    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder(str);
    StringBuilder filtered = new StringBuilder();

    for (int start = s.indexOf(open), end = s.indexOf(close, start + 1); start != -1; 
        start = s.indexOf(open), end = s.indexOf(close, start + 1)){
        filtered.append(s.substring(start + open_length, end)).append(", ");
        s.delete(0, end + close_length);
    }

    return filtered.substring(0, filtered.length() - 2); //trailing ", "
}
```

This iterative method makes use of `StringBuilder`, but the same can be done without it. It makes two `StringBuilder`s, one empty one, and one that holds the value of the original `String`. In the `for` loop:

- `int start = s.indexOf(open), end = s.indexOf(close)` gets a reference to the indices
- `start != -1` ends the loop if `s` does not contain `open`
- `start = s.indexOf(open), end = s.indexOf(close)` after each iteration of the loop, find the indices again.

The inside of the loop appends the correct substring to `finished` and removes the appended part from the other `StringBuilder`.

Comment: perhaps this is my last choice solution. but can we do it without regex?

Comment: @RafaEl What do you have against regex? Also, I would not use a recursive solution; iterative seems much simpler

Comment: thank you for your effort to help. cant wait to go through on this solution later. actually i've declared String filtered in main method, and the codes is working just fine, unless i use delimiter such as ''' and ''', as i mention in the question.

Comment: @RafaEl see the note right after the header "Non-regex Solutions:". You need to use [`String#indexOf(String, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Never mind all that code in other answers... You can do it in one line:

```
String[] urls = str.replaceAll("^.*?'''\\[|\\]'''(?!.*\\]''').*", "").split("\\]'''.*?'''\\[");
```

This first strips off the leading and trailing jetsam and then splits on a delimiter that matches everything between the targets.

---

This can be adapted to a flexible solution that has variable delimiters:

```
public static String[] extract(String str, String open, String close) {
    return str.replaceAll("^.*?(\\Q" + open + "\\E|$)|\\Q" + close + "\\E(?!.*\\Q" + close + "\\E).*", "").split("\\Q" + close + "\\E.*?\\Q" + open + "\\E");
}
```

This regex also caters for there being no targets by returning an array with a single blank element.

P.S. this is the first time I can recall using the quote syntax `\Q...\E` to treat characters in the regex as literals, so I'm chuffed about that.

I would also like to claim some bragging rights for typing the whole thing on my iPhone (note that means there could be a character or two out of place, but it should be pretty close).

Comment: Aye it can be done in one line. However, I feel that code-readability is important. Also, if you read the entire question, you will see that the OP wants to be able to specify the delimiters. Yes, I included a lot of code, but only after the OP told me he didn't want to use regex.

Comment: This probably the simplest solution that can replace my current solution in the question. but, yes, I do stated that the delimiters may changing and i'm looking for a flexible solution since I will use this class for all similar situation in my project.

Comment: Wow, this is the first time I noticed that your profile picture is not a bear.... I didn't realize that it is the [common wombat](http://goo.gl/58khqL)

Comment: @rafael OK - see post now

Comment: @Quincunx well I'm an Aussie, and I think wombats are cute (well cuter than me anyway). P.S. see edited post for flexible delimiter solution.

Comment: @Bohemian wow impressive. it will takes me 1 whole day to study your code:/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the string tokenizer for this very easily. Simply hand the whole string to the tokenizer then ask for each token and check if it begins with your delimiter. If it does, extract the contents into your results collection.

The string tokenizer version will be less upped and not as ugly as the regent solution.

Here is the tokenizer version:

```
public class TokenizerTest {

    @Test
    public void canExtractNamesFromTokens(){
        String openDelimiter = "'''[";
        String closeDelimiter = "]'''";
        String s="social network such as '''[http://www.facebook.com Facebook]''' , "+
            "'''[http://www.twitter.com Twitter]''' and '''[http://www.tumblr.com tumblr]'''";

        StringTokenizer t = new StringTokenizer(s);

        while (t.hasMoreElements()){
            String token = t.nextToken();
            if (token.startsWith(openDelimiter)){
                String url = token.substring(openDelimiter.length());
                token = t.nextToken();
                String siteName = token.substring(0, token.length()-closeDelimiter.length());
                System.out.println(url + " " + siteName);
            }
        }
   }
}
```

Not sure how this could get any simpler or cleaner. Absolutely clear what the code is doing.

Comment: How would this work? `StringTokenizer` uses delimiters separating the wanted values. The OP wants to find the `String`s within certain substrings, but not the other parts.

Comment: The default delimiter is space. So it would give me each token then I could check for the other delimiter ([). Regex is great for complex patterns, which this is not.

Comment: "died auk"? No idea what that means. Can you show what you would do with the `StringTokenizer`? I don't get what you would do.